# Retain observations whose NA is <= 20% of total variables

Tags: r, data-cleaning, na, missing-data

Suppose we have this dataframe with six observations and four variables

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, NA, NA, 4, NA, 5),
                 b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1),
                 c = c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA, 6),
                 d = c(6, 7, NA, NA, 4, 4))
```

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA | 1 | 6 |
| NA | NA | 2 | 7 |
| NA | NA | 3 | NA |
| 4 | NA | 4 | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | 4 |
| 5 | 1 | 6 | 4 |

How can we retain observations whose NA's does not exceed 50% of the variables? (In this case each observation left will have two NA's at most; thus only 4 observations will be retained.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `rowSums()` to count up the NAs in each row. Then you discard the rows with more than `threshold*ncol(df)` NAs in their row.

```
threshold <- 0.5

df <- df[-which(rowSums(is.na(df)) > threshold*ncol(df)), ]
```